# Rolling back a file

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I have a situation, a colleage of mine overwrote PHP files that I've made changes to , is it possible to roll back a file to a previous working version using the command line. No svn repositories are available and also not any backups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that if you didn't make any backups, you're almost certainly SOL here, especially from the command line.

Unlinking (deleting) a file can sometimes leave the data recoverable as long as nothing else grabs that particular inode; editing a file overwrites the data.

If your colleague still has the editor he was working in open and its undo buffer is long enough, that *might* be a way to recover the original, but beyond that I'm afraid you're sunk. Sorry.

Comment: Thanx for the response, busy setting up a SVN repository, just thought maybe maybe there's a chance of getting it back

Comment: I usually just tarball my work and delete that tarball every once in a while. But I'd seriously consider `git`, `hg`, of `svn` to backup your code. You can even schedule it to commit every few hours with `cron` if you have to.

Comment: @Roland Consider using `git`, after some learning it's so easy to use and so fast, so you'll never think about not versioning anything (and you'll not understand how you ever could use `svn`). I need less than one minute to create a repo for a new project, to commit, and to clone to a server. Just my opinion, not gonna start a flame war.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using ext3, it might be possible to recover it if the replacement file was created as another inode (instead of overwriting the existing file), by using `debugfs` on the unmounted filesystem, and to find the inode of the original file.  Unfortunately, if your colleage overwrite the file, rather than moving it aside and then deleting it, it's gone.  I would suggest using `debugfs` with **extreme caution**, because you can seriously mess up a filesystem.  It's use is only really for a last-ditch effort.

Comment: @thanks, no unfortunately it wasn't created as a inode, thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you would have a tmp file created which begin with `~filename.extension`. You can recover from that.